# Why does type A >: Number means a container that store Number instances?

Tags: scala

[scala types of type](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/)

says

> The more interesting uses of Abstract Type Members start when we apply
>   constraints to them. For example imagine you want to have a container
>   that can only store Number instances. Such constraint can be annotated
>   on a type member right where we defined it first:

```
trait OnlyNumbersContainer {
  type A >: Number
  def value: A
}
```

but `A` as defined here is a `supertype` of Number shouldn't it be then

`A <: Number` meaning I need `A` to be a subtype of `Number`?

Comment: "Only" is a bit misleading, but this is a type that can definitely store `Number`s - it might be e.g. a `Container[Number]`, but it could also be a `Container[Any]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type A >: Number` where A being the supertype of Number is correct : ([refer](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/lower-type-bounds.html)). Which corresponds to having properties like Numbers to begin with but can span to Any.

The one you mentioned `A <: Number` refers to the upper bound being number essentially A being a subtype.

For the statement, only storing Number instances should refer to `type A = Number`.